# Android ListView with section titles

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I need to set up a ListView that has section titles.

I have my data formatted as such

List is the root
    Each entry has:
        a day field (which will be the section title)
        a classes field which is a JSONArray
           The classes JSONArray has a number of JSONObjects in it containing text I need to display in the list

If I want to display the above data as  section ListView would I be better separating the data into 2 Lists? Or could I do it all in the one list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [MergeAdapter commons ware](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge)

Example:

```
mergeAdapter = new MergeAdapter(); 
mergeAdapter.addView(sectionView1); 
mergeAdapter.addAdapter(listAdapter1); 
mergeAdapter.addView(sectionView2); 
mergeAdapter.addAdapter(listAdapter2);
```

And later set this adapter to your list

Comment: I'm gonna use that adapter a LOT! Much easier that some tutorials I was reading, and much easier than the idea I had of looping through my data and adding views to a parent view.